# How can I achieve USB 3.0 transfer speeds (5 Gbps) on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, mac, usb

All lightning cables that I have used with my iPhone up until now have transferred data at a maximum of 480 Mbps. This is indicative of USB 2.0 connector speeds.

However, after researching this topic I'm quite confused. How do I transfer data between my Mac and my iPhone at USB 3.0 speeds? Do I need to lighting to USB C cable? Are there any lightning cables that transfer data at USB 3.0 speeds? Does my iPhone even support USB 3.0 speeds? I'm really confused and I can't find specifications for this *anywhere*.

What's even stranger is that my iPad Pro 11 can transfer data at USB 3.0 speeds via the USB port—and that's the only time I've ever seen such speed between a macOS and an iOS device.

I would like to know to achieve USB 3.0 speeds while transferring data to my iPhone. To do this, I would like to know, which iPhones support data transfer at USB 3.0 speeds in the first place, and which cable I need to use to transfer data at USB 3.0 speeds.

Comment: One question per question is the best tactic here. Down votes often sink a question that has one good clear question and a bunch of side questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only iDevivce that support USB 3.0 speeds over the lightning connector is the iPad Pro released in 2015.  Current iPad Pro Tablets with the USB-C connector support USB 3.

All other devices only support 2.0.

> Do I need to lighting to USB C cable?

USB-C is just the *physical* port type.  To get USB 3 speeds, you need at least a USB 3.0 port (blue connector in the Type A connector).    As for the the specific port specification, Apple takes its classic “remain vague” tactic.  All it says is it’s connectivity is “USB-C” not which USB spec it conforms to (i.e. USB 3.1 Gen 1).

Comment: "Apple takes its classic “remain vague” tactic"—this is very true, and I was surprised to not find any discussion about it online either